# How do I unsubscribe my AWS organization from CloudTrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower

I'm trying to create an AWS Control Tower landing zone for my AWS organization, and am getting a message saying `You must unsubscribe your organization from AWS CloudTrail so that AWS Control Tower can proceed. During the setup process, AWS Control Tower creates a new trail in the audit account that's part of your landing zone.` How do I do this? Does this mean stopping all CloudTrail trails from sending logs, or is there an organization-wide setting to disable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS Control Tower needs trusted access to be disabled for both Cloudtrail and Config. To disable this you need to login into the Organization management account, and go to *AWS Organizations > Services > Disable Config/Cloudtrail*.

Trusted access enabled at an Organization level enables these services to inject service roles in all member accounts where they need to change something. Disabling this for Cloudtrail would result in the Organization trail not working anymore, however the master trail would still be intact. All shadow trails in member accounts would be disabled. AWS still allows you to search/filter/download cloudtrail management events in each of the member accounts for last 90 days, just that they wouldn't be transferred to a central s3 bucket for storage.